# DELETE query running too long

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

I know this might be redundant but I have had the same query running for almost 3 days and before I kill it, I would like to get a community sanity check.

```
DELETE
FROM    mytble
WHERE   ogc_fid NOT IN
    (SELECT     MAX(dup.ogc_fid)
        FROM        mytble As dup
        GROUP BY    dup.id)
```

`mytble` is the name of the table, `ogc_fid` is the name of the unique id field and `id` is the name of the field that I *want* to be the unique id. There are 41 million records in the table and indexes are built and everything so I am still a bit concerned about why its taking so long to complete. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Add a query plan to your question.

Comment: Might it be simpler just select the unique records into a new table (then drop the old one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to delete all the records for which a record with the same dup_id
(but with a higher ogc_fid) exists. And keep only those with the highest ogc_fid.

```
-- DELETE -- uncomment this line and comment the next line if proven innocent.
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM   mytble mt
 WHERE   EXISTS (
  SELECT *
    FROM mytble nx
   WHERE nx.dup_id = mt.dup_id    -- there exists a row with the same dup_id
     AND nx.ogc_fid > mt.ogc_fid  -- , ... but with a higher ogc_fid 
);
```

With an index on dup_id (and maybe on ogc_id) this should run maybe a few minutes for 41M records.

UPDATE: if no indexes exist, you could speed up the above queries by first creating an index:

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sinterklaas ON mytble (dup_id, ogc_id);
```

Comment: Basically I have a table with a lot of duplicate records and I want to delete them. the duplicates are identified in the id field and the unique id column is called ogc_fid. So, I would like to remove the duplicates based on the id field. Does this make more sense?

Comment: You mean: if duplicates for a certain entity exist they will have the same dup_id (but different ogc_fid's). I'll ad an index definition. Also replacing the "DELETE FROM" by "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM" -trick enables you to inspect the affected rows (and estimated running time) of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Would be nice if you provided `explain` output, but what you're doing *might* be faster when done like this (again, I'd look up `explain`):

```
DELETE FROM mytable d
USING mytable m
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(ogc_fid) AS f FROM mytble GROUP BY id) AS q ON m.ogc_fid=q.f
WHERE d.ogc_fid=m.ogc_fid AND q.f IS NULL;
```

Comment: I was able to solve this by using a combination of both your answers! Thanks to both of you for the code snippets!